# Word or phrase representing nostalgia as well as pride?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

My grandfather remembers the war, which he was a part of. He is proud of the fact that they won, and he is also  nostalgic as he remembers those days. He is/feeling _____________.

Comment: Sentimental, perhaps.

Comment: @Ricky - There goes my answer! :P I was just composing this as my answer and boom, arrives your comment! I request you to post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: It's your answer, so you post it. I don't mind.

Comment: Sentimental is nice, but does it also indicate pride?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single word that encapsulates both the emotions of *nostalgia* and *pride*. Perhaps your grandfather is feeling ***[sentimental](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sentimental)*** about the war he fought

> (adj.) expressive of or appealing to sentiment, especially the tender emotions and feelings, as love, pity, or nostalgia

[Dictionary.com]

Or if you're looking for an idiom, consider

***[take pride in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+pride+in)***

> to be proud of someone or something

[Dictionary.com]

**Usage:**

> My *nostalgic* grandfather ***took a great deal of pride in*** winning the war which he was part of.

Comment: If there's an other word or phrase which you can think of I'll be grateful :P

Answer (score -2):

You can use reminiscence or memoirs maybe:

> **[Reminiscence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reminiscence)**: the act or process of recalling past experiences, events, etc.
>
> **[Memoirs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/memoirs?s=t)**: a record of events written by a person having intimate knowledge of them and based on personal observation.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please see how to write [good answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) which will make your contributions all the more worthier. In this case, memoirs happen to be written notes of the past, in most cases. Not an emotion.

Comment: When answering a single word request please include a helpful explanation as to why a particular word is suitable. Remember: you are answer for people who don't already know the answer.